# what is the script-able equivalent to the user command "apt list --installed"?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt

I can do these commands nicely on the command line of my Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) installation:

```
apt list --installed
apt list --installed | grep grep
```

Stdout receives the results and also this line:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

When putting this into a script I assume i have to use something like "apt-get" or "apt-cache" - but when trying that neither of it supports my given options. Instead i am getting:

```
E: Command line option --installed is not understood in combination with the other options
```

After removing the "--installed" part, i am getting this:

```
E: Invalid operation list
```

Which is the command line tool variant of apt that should be used for doing this query in a stable fashion? (I definitely hope for a tools variant that wont issue those "WARNING:" line.)

Comment: Try the granddaddy of all apt-based package managers `dpkg`.
The command you want is `dpkg -l` and `dpkg -l | grep searchterm`.
Personally, I never use  `apt`, or any of the `apt-*` commands.  I use `aptitude`instead.  To each their own.

Answer (score 3):

**[Aptitude](https://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude) package search with customize formatting.**

When searching packages with aptitude, [search terms](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) are used to limit the search, in this case 'installed' packages. Pattern are then performed using  case-insensitive [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (by adding '^' '$' anchors to the pattern exact package name can be matched). With `-F` option a customized output format string can be formed by using [%escapes](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html).

**Example:**

```bash
$ aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, "^grep$")' -F '%p (%v)' -q=2 --disable-columns
  grep (3.3-1)
```

**(Script example with short search terms)**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -r package_name package_version < <(aptitude search '~i^grep$' -F '%p %v' -q=2 --disable-columns 2>&-)

echo $package_name
echo $package_version

exit 0
```

**Search term reference:**
   ?narrow() - Select packages for which a single version matches both filter and pattern.
   ?installed - Select installed packages.

**Escape placeholders:**
   %p - Outputs the name of the package.
   %v - Outputs the currently installed version of the package.

**Aptitude options**:
   -F - Specify the format which should be used to display output.
   -q - Suppress all progress indicators. Supplied multiple times makes the output quieter.
   --disable-columns - This option causes search to output their results without any special formatting.

**Get package selections with [dpkg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html).**

```bash
$ dpkg --get-selections grep
  grep                                            install
```

or

```bash
$ dpkg -l grep
  ii  grep           3.3-1        amd64        GNU grep, egrep and fgrep
```

**(Script example)**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(dpkg --get-selections grep 2>&-) =~ .+[[:space:]]+install$ ]]; then
  echo Installed
fi
```

or

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if (( $(dpkg -l grep 2>&- | grep -c ^ii) == 1 )); then
  echo Installed
fi
```

**Get package status with [dpkg-query](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-query.1.html).**

```
$ dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\t${Version} (${db:Status-Status})\n' --show grep
  grep    3.3-1 (installed)
```

**(Script example)**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(dpkg-query --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' --show grep 2>&-) == 'installed' ]]; then
  echo Installed
fi
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that `aptitude` hasn't been included in the default Ubuntu install for years.

Comment: it looks to me like there is no "stable" and thus useable CLI variant from the apt-... family of tools. seemingly only dpkg and aptitude are coming with such a promise...